# C#/.NET POST request keeps returning 400 Bad Request in controller

Tags: c#, bad-request

I am trying to write a simple API te receive POST requests with a body. When I try to test my method it keeps resulting in a 400 bad request in Postman. I first thought the issue was with deserializing the JSON body. So to be sure I stripped out that logic from the controller, but the request still returned a 400 status code.

So I removed everything from my method except for the method itself, only returning `Ok('Hello World');` and still the response was a 400.

What I have left for now is this:

```
  [Route("api/v1/service/")]
  public class ServiceController : Controller
  {

    public ServiceController()
    {

    }

    [HttpGet("get")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
      return Ok("GET works fine");
    }

    [HttpPost("post")]
    public IActionResult Post()
    {
      return Ok("Hello World"); // <-- Keeps returning 400
    }

  }
```

The GET method works fine, but when I sent an empty POST call to `/api/v1/service/post` in Postman I get a bad request.

I also noticed that when I change the route to something different or random that does not exists it also gets a 400, instead of a 404.

So making a POST call to `api/v1/service/this-route-is-not-defined` also results in a bad request.

I keep changing small things in my request form adding/removing ContentType or Accept headers and adjusting my `StartUp.cs` . But every POST call I make to .NET seems to result in a 400 status code.

## Edit

This might be related to the routing in `Startup.cs`:

```
      app.UseHsts();

      app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
      });
      app.UseRouting();
```

This is the request in POST man:

GET:
[image]

POST:
[image]

The code in the sample was offcourse altered from my original API method, but the idea is the same. I copied the sample to a new file in my project and clicked in Postman on create new request. So headers are the default ones.

Comment: you should post to `/api/v1/service/post`, in question you're mentioning `/api/v1/service/`

Comment: @KamilBudziewski Thanks, offcourse I am making a request to `/api/v1/service/post`

Comment: Add the `Startup.cs` class, maybe you have misconfigured routing.

Comment: @Max I have quite a lot of code in my Startup.cs, is there a specific part I should be looking for?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add the Postman screenshots for GET and POST?

Comment: @AnindyaDey i have added the screenshots, just clicked on create new request to get a blank request. Headers are default. Also I would like to add that I am running my code from an external module separate from the main project. So there is a main.csproj were the module is being referenced to. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I am using dotnet 6

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the answers and comments given to this question were all helpfull.

I found the culprit. Apperently there was an option enabled in the `Startup.cs` file that puts an anti-forgery token check on all API calls that can modify stuff, like POST, PUT, DELETE. This is not an issue when calling the API from the frontend with a Javascript `fetch()` for instance. The token is added to a tag in the document and you can add to the request headers like this:

`headers.append('X-XSRF-TOKEN', (document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0] as any).value)`

To be able to make a POST call from Postman for instance you can add this line temporarely above your action.

`[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]`

So working example would like this:

```
  [Route("api/v1/service/")]
  public class ServiceController : Controller
  {

    public ServiceController()
    {

    }

    [HttpGet("get")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
      return Ok("GET works fine");
    }

    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    [HttpPost("post")]
    public IActionResult Post()
    {
      return Ok("Hello World"); // <-- Keeps returning 400
    }

  }
```

It is important to think about when to use `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` and not to use it. On methods that allready expect an API key for instance you can use it in a production environment. But when method is public the anti-forgery token is a way of protecting your method from attackers or people/robots trying to spam your API.

Comment: I would check your setup, it looks like your configured for MVC (hence anti forgery being added by default), rather than Web API. If you are using cookie auth though, and want to use anti forgery in your Web API [this is how you do it](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/11/29/asp-net-core-web-api-antiforgery/).

Answer (score 1):

### Your missing MapControllers()

In your startup.cs add `MapControllers()`, this is required for attribute based routing.

```
app.MapControllers();
```

If the version of .NET you are using is < 6.0 then add like so:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

##### [MapControllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.controllerendpointroutebuilderextensions.mapcontrollers) is called to map attribute routed controllers.

Comment: What is the namespace of .MapController()? I'm getting `'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapControllers' and the best extension method overload 'ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder)' requires a receiver of type 'IEndpointRouteBuilder'`

Comment: I allrwady have `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`
`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core;` and `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;`

Comment: It's def Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder, try the second example in your using Startup.cs. It looks like your using an older style template, rather than the [minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).